# pam account locking is not working on RHEL7

Tags: authentication, locking, account, pam, rhel7

I have used the configuration on RHEL website below, however PAM account locking is not working as expected. Even though i have unlocked user manually on root, i can not login with that user and I can not even login with any user after these settings applied(expect root). Am i missing some other setting on other files like sshd or else?

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/chap-Hardening_Your_System_with_Tools_and_Services.html#sect-Security_Guide-Workstation_Security-Account_Locking

My configurations on /etc/pam.d/system-auth and /etc/pam.d/password-auth files...

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent audit deny=3 unlock_time=600
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 unlock_time=600
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_faillock.so
```

BR,

Utku

Answer (score 0):

Please use this to lock accounts after failed logins

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=4 even_deny_root unlock_time=1200
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so


account     required      pam_tally2.so
```

Please update both password-auth and system-auth, if you want to allow root to access please remove even_deny_root part

You can monitor failed attempts by using

```
pam_tally2
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... I have added `even_deny_root` to pam_faillock preauth and moved pam_unix nullok file a step down.

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth silent even_deny_root audit deny=3 unlock_time=600
auth        [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
unlock_time=600
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_faillock.so
```